# Creating secure communications with Apache server

Tags: apache, ssl

I am currently developing a web application which will have forms and login, so I want to make the connection secure, that is, through HTTPS using SSL but I have never used SSL before, only read about it and my search on the internet has not been a success so far. So any help on creating SSL for this purpose or maybe providing me with a link on where I can learn on how to will be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: on which OS you wanted to implement apache and SSL?                                          Read....https://www.linux.com/learn/creating-self-signed-ssl-certificates-apache-linux

Comment: On windows OS @NitinDhomse